# get position of target after dragstop

Tags: jsplumb

How can get the position of the connection target when I stop dragging. I tried this, but I think the element is already removed by then:

```
jsPlumb.bind("connectionDragStop", function(info){
    console.log(info.target.position())
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I guess the problem is wrong syntax. As per I have learnt these days it should be like

`jsPlumb.bind("connectionDragStop", function(info){
    console.log(info.targetId.position()) ;
})`

because here info will be your connection object. And it have property as targetId. All the best :-)