# Extend jsplumb.draggable drag behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I am sure that I am missing something here, but I would like to extend the drag behavior of a div with jsPlumb.draggable class attributes that is attached to an endpoint, while preserving the jsPlumb.draggable attributes.

I would like something like this (adapted from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903530/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-draggable-object)):

```
$('#dragcodes').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        console.log('x: ' + xPos);
        console.log('y: ' + yPos);
    }
});
```

on an element that is created using:

```
jsPlumb.draggable($(".dragcodes"));
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jimcrozier/jnPD5/1/) of what I am trying to do. I want the top box to read the position out on drag like the bottom one is, but cannot figure out how to hack the drag: function in jsPlumb.draggable. The binding behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599321/get-position-of-target-after-dragstop) is getting close, but I want to target the div that is attached to the endpoint. If I override the drag: functionality, I lose the jsPlumb.draggable attributes. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jsPlumb.draggable helps to update the DOM element whenever it is dragged. Instead you can write that code in jQuery draggable as:

```
$('#dragcodes').draggable(
{
    drag: function(){
    jsPlumb.repaint($(this)); // (or) jsPlumb.repaintEverything(); to repaint the connections and endpoints
    //followed by your code
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = offset.left;
    var yPos = offset.top;
    console.log('x: ' + xPos);
    console.log('y: ' + yPos);
}
});
```

Now there is no need for `jsPlumb.draggable($(".dragcodes"));`

Comment: Actually this solution cause a performance hit if you have a lot of elements

Answer (score 7):

In Version 1.6.3 the following Code works:

```
jsPlumb.draggable("#dragcodes", {
  drag: function (event, ui) { //gets called on every drag
    console.log(ui.position);  //ui.position.left and ui.position.top
  }
});
```

Comment: good call. this is a better solution IMHO. This works in 1.5.5 as well

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work anymore: ui is undefined. Version 1.7.10

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to configure `DragOptions` of [`jsPlumb.Defaults`](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/defaults.html). You have to specify `drag` function:

```
jsPlumb.getInstance({
....,
DragOptions: {
  drag: function() {
  }
},
....
);
```

Answer (score 0):

JsPlumb Version 2.1.4

```
jsPlumb.draggable("#yourElement", {
  drag: function (event) {
    console.log(event.pos[0]); // for left position
    console.log(event.pos[1]); // for top position
  }
);
```

Or

```
jsPlumb.draggable("#yourElement", {
  drag: function (event) {
    $(event.el).position().left; // for left position
    $(event.el).position().top; // for top position
  }
);
```