# Deleting an element after jsPlumb.draggable() in a droppable's drop: function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, jsplumb

I want to make a delete area, where any element which is dropped gets deleted.
Hence I implemented this as a droppable with `drop:function(event,ui){ui.helper.remove()}`.
This doesn't work with `jsPlumb.draggable()`.

[The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snugghash/bqSp5/)

This works fine when I make the elements draggable with Jquery UI `$(...).draggable()`.
Hence it appears that `jsPlumb.draggable($(...),{})` doesn't use a helper. Calling `ui.draggable.remove()` deletes many more elements.

I think there's nothing in jsPlumb documentation or StackOverflow about this specific issue.

Any ideas?
Now the best solution would be without an `elseif` ladder to check for various implementations from various plugins, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that with jQuery draggable everything works fine then I would suggest you to replace the jsPlumb draggable as:

```
droppedEleClone.draggable({
                snap: '.dragme',
                drag:function(e){
                    jsPlumb.repaint($(this));
                }
            });
```

And also while cloning make sure that you provide different ID's. DOM elements having same ID's doesn't yield proper result.
Because of cloning the same object it's difficult to identify the right one and deleting it. Hence provide different ID's.

Comment: I was hoping for something from jsPlumb, or why this is happening in the first place. Your solution solves the problem, I'll accept when 24 hours have passed.

Comment: @snugghash `jsPlumb.draggable` overrides the `jQuery.draggable` hence the drop function will not be invoked. If you need to invoke the `.drop` function then you must extend the `jQuery.draggable` function as mentioned above to update the jsPlumb connections manually. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818899/extend-jsplumb-draggable-drag-behavior