# Bind the endpoint to a clone in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I have a drag and drop applications, and I'm trying add connecting points using jsPlumb. I have toolbar of components, and the user can drag and drop components to the canvas.

Once they drop an item, I creating a clone and assign a unique id for the clone using jQuery UI. On the double click of the clone, I'm trying to add an end point on the top, and I have successfully managed to add the endpoint. but when I drag the component, the end point does not drag with it.

Following is my code.

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {

//providing dragging for .drag class components
$(".drag").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  tolerance: 'fit',
  stop: function (ev, ui) {

      var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
      objName = "#clone" + count;

      $(objName).removeClass("drag");

      $(objName).draggable({
            cancel: ".arrows"
      });


      //When an existing object is dragged
      //objName is the clone and providing dragging option it
      $(objName).draggable({
          containment: '#droppable',
          stop: function (ev, ui) {   

          }
      });
  },
  revert: true 
});

$("#droppable").droppable({

  accept: '.drag',
  activeClass: "drop-area",
  drop: function (e, ui) {


      if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {

         count++;


         x = ui.helper.clone();
         $(this).append(x.attr("id",'clone'+count));

         ui.helper.remove();


    var offsetXPos = ui.offset.left;
        var offsetYPos = ui.offset.top;



        var clone = ui.draggable;
        var width = clone.width();
        var height = clone.height();

        var obj = {};

            obj["cloneID"] =  'clone'+count;
            obj["width"] = 85;
            obj["height"] = 91;
            obj["top"] = offsetYPos;
            obj["left"] = offsetXPos;

        var str = eval(obj);
        jsonElements.push(str);


          $("#clone"+count).dblclick(function(event) {


              var sourceUUID = "xxx";
             //addindg the end point to the clone
             instance.addEndpoint('clone'+count, sourceEndpoint, {
                    anchor : "TopCenter",
                    uuid : sourceUUID
                });




             instance.draggable(jsPlumb.getSelector(".droppable .window"),
        {
            grid : [ 20, 20 ]
        }); 


          }); 


          x.appendTo('#droppable');

      }
  }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It happened because 'ui-draggable' css class is still present on the cloned object. after i remove it dynamically using $("#clone"+count).removeClass("ui-draggable") it worked fine. Hope this will help some one.

Comment: Instead of removing the jQuery draggable you can extend it functionality to update the endpoints and connections as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818899/extend-jsplumb-draggable-drag-behavior/20836379#20836379